# How to get row data from web table in Karate framework

Tags: karate, karate-call-single

The web table has a  combination of textbox, span and checkboxes. I need to get first row of all the data in single def  and have to verify with DB in order wise.

Ex: First row of table has columns like below.

OrderID(span), EmpName(input), IsHeEligible(checkbox), Address(span)

By using below,

```
def tebleFirstData = scriptAll("table/tbody/tr/td",'_.textContent')
```

Able to get only span text data, not able to get input tag test data.

I tried below,

```
data = attribute("table/tbody/tr/td[5]/input",'value')
```

But, I'm able to get only single input tag attribute value.

How can I get all the data in single def, i.e span data and input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution to get all row data from table..!

```
 * def UiFirstRowElements = locateAll("Row xpath")
```

- print UiFirstRowElements
- def tableData = []

  - def RowHtml =  UiFirstRowElements[0].html
  - print RowHtml
- eval
  """
  for(var i=0; i<UiFirstRowElements.length; i++)
  if(UiFirstRowElements[i].html.contains("input") && UiFirstRowElements[i].html.contains("date")){
  tableData.push(locate("//table/tbody/tr/td["+(i+1)+"]/div/input").property('value'))
  }
  else if(UiFirstRowElements[i].html.contains("input") && UiFirstRowElements[i].html.contains("checkbox")){
  tableData.push(locate("//table/tbody/tr/td["+(i+1)+"]/div/input").property('checked'))
  }
  else {
  tableData.push(locate("//table/tbody/tr/td["+(i+1)+"]").property('textContent'))
  }
  """
  * print 'TableName-->', TableName
  * print tableData